# Selenium Frames

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am having problems selecting items in a frame. I get to a certain point and then it fails.  I have tried a lot of options but to
no avail, below is the code. I get into the first frame and then:

```
selenium.open("http://localhost/Clockwise/Main.htm");
// grabs back to driver
WebDriver driver = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getWrappedDriver(); 
driver.switchTo().frame("MainFrame");
//selenium.selectFrame("MainFrame");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Reports')]")).click();
//selenium.click("//li[contains(.,'Reports')]")  

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Reports')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Reports')]"));

Thread.sleep(3000);

//FAILS HERE
driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTALL2")).click();
```

Answer (score 8):

After your actions/operations completed in iframe you need to switch back to main window or defaul content

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame");
driver.findElement(By.id("test")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTALL2")).click();
```

You've missed 3rd statement in above code.